# Input command into ruby while timer is running?

Tags: ruby, timer, sleep

I'm building a text-based adventure game, and I have an instance where the user encounters an enemy, and has 3 seconds to react. My timer code looks like this:

```
def timer
  puts "1"
  sleep(2)
  puts "2"
  sleep(2)
  puts "3"
  sleep(2)
end
```

This works, but while printing 1,2,3 to the console, it won't let me input a command. So I want the user to be able to type 'attack' for example while the timer runs. At the moment the command can be inputted during the timer but it won't register on the console until after the timer is done. Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the timer on a different thread:

```
def timer
  Thread.new do
    puts "1"
    sleep(2)
    puts "2"
    sleep(2)
    puts "3"
    sleep(2)
  end
end
```

Now you can listen to input while the timer runs. You still need to communicate back to your main logic when the timer expires...

Comment: Thanks Uri that solves my problem!
However, while printing 1,2,3 to the screen, the users input clashes with the numbers being printed. E.g. while typing attack, the number 2 is printed and ruby won't recognise 2attack. I need the 1,2,3 to be independent of the user's input. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3315570 - AFAIK they are not supposed to clash. print the input, make sure it is what you think it is...